# Downloading JSON using httpclient

Tags: java, json, caching, httpclient, threadpool

I would like to download JSON feeds periodically from my application in order to parse with GSON or Jackson.
I looked at the following examples of httpclient http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/examples.html 
I had a few questions:

1. I would like to add caching to it
   I used the CachingHttpClient as described in the http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/caching.html. and fetched a URL 5 times in a loop to test. However, each time I get a cache miss. I wonder what I would be doing wrong.
2. I saw the example of multithreaded request execution where a thread is created for each URL. Is this the recommended way? I was thinking more in terms of a threadpool where x urls could be given to a fixed pool of say 10 threads.
3. Probably, once I have clarity on the above two I may be in a position to implement a cached threadpooled httpclient.

Thanks,
Aditya